# Creating Flooding depth Rasters at every feet

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder

I am explaining the issue I am facing to automate the process.

I have created a DEM from LIDAR and the Asset elevation is incorporated into the surface.

Purpose of this task: Once I get the new asset Elevation, then I need to incorporate those asset elevations in the previously created LiDAR surface.

We need to automate the below mentioned process so that every time the surface is modified, the flood depth raster’s from 1 feet to 12 feet will automatically generate after running the script.

Here you will observe that Raster surface elevation is indirectly proportional to the Flood depth rasters.

One more thing you will observe that the flooding depth color is same for each feet.

Please let me know if you need more explanation.

How to set up the raster classification in this case?

Precipitation/Stormwater color used:

[image]

[image]

Setting Exclusion properties

[image: Setting Exclusion properties]

Flooding depth rasters at 12 ft and 5ft

[image]

Comment: You cannot do this automatically without setting up a template for every permutation of maximum elevation. See more at this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82335/how-to-programmatically-change-raster-symbology-after-reclassification

Comment: To add to this, you would be much better off using map algebra to generate a separate flood depth raster and then symbolizing that raster the exact same way every time (e.g. have some maximum depth, I used 10 feet, that is the top of the scale and then symbology every depth raster with the same 0 to 10 symbology)

Comment: You seem not to have completed this sentence "I have created a DEM from LIDAR and the Asset elevation is incorporated into the"

Comment: @PolyGeo : updated!!